# String.valueOf() in a loop

Tags: java

I am trying to add elements to a Queue using a for-loop

```
for(int i = 1; i <= cars.size(); i++){
    cars.add(new vehicle(String.valueOf(i));
}
```

When I try to peek at the queue, I am getting hashcode representations instead of the actual value of i. How can I get the values of i?

Comment: You are getting the hashcode of `vehicle` (not `i`).

Comment: The queue presumably contains `vehicle` instances, not strings...

Comment: how does this loop even terminate?